# Tell sidenotes package to use left / right ragged alignment

Tags: captions, alignment, marginnote, sidenotes

The `sidenotes` package is supposedly using the `\marginnote` command, but I'm getting a justified text rather than a left / right ragged one.
I'm a little confused.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \sidecaption{\lipsum[66]}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:my_labela}
\end{figure}
\marginnote{\footnotesize\lipsum[66]}[-4.5cm]
\newpage
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \sidecaption{\lipsum[66]}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:my_labelb}
\end{figure}
\marginnote{\footnotesize\lipsum[66]}[-4.5cm]

\end{document}
```

[image: right page]
[image: left page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{font=footnotesize, justification=raggedright}`

[image: a]

The manual is not very explicit on how to set the caption styles:

> Please refer to the *caption* manual for details on styles.

The package `caption` defines

```
 \DeclareCaptionFormat{name}{code} % name is the name of the caption format

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{name}{code}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{name}{code}
```

and others. Also the command `\DeclareCaptionStyle`
.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{graphics}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{font=footnotesize, justification=raggedright}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \sidecaption{\lipsum[66]}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:my_label1}
    \end{figure}
    \marginnote{\footnotesize\lipsum[66]}[-4.5cm]
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** After follow-up suggestion: option `twoside` for book

**Page 1**

[image: d]

**Page 2**

[image: e]

This is the complete updated code.

**Note:** To detect odd or even page it is needed to have`\RequirePackage[strict]{changepage}` (which in this case is  done by `sidenotes`).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}% loads \RequirePackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage[outer=7cm, inner=2cm, marginparwidth=5cm,marginparsep=5mm,showframe]{geometry}% show & large margins <<<    

%%********************************************************************
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{font=footnotesize, justification=twoside}% added <<<  
\DeclareCaptionJustification{twoside}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage \raggedright \else \raggedleft \fi
}
%%********************************************************************

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \sidecaption{\lipsum[66]}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    \marginnote{\footnotesize\lipsum[66]}[-4cm]
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \sidecaption{\lipsum[66]}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    \marginnote{\footnotesize\lipsum[66]}[-4cm]
    \lipsum[2]  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you find out? I did read the source, but couldn't understand that. More precisely, where is `\DeclareCaptionStyle` defined? Also, it should be `raggedright` for right notes but `raggedleft` for left notes. `\marginnote[<left>]{<right>}[<voffset>]` has a left / right option for this reason.

Comment: I see… The `caption` package is defining that. Digging further :D

Comment: Fixed it! Found the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499926/33287! Please, add  `\DeclareCaptionJustification{raggedauto}{\checkoddpage \ifoddpage \raggedright \else \raggedleft \fi}` to your solution and replace `raggedright` with `raggedauto`.

Comment: @Atcold I  will do it later. You might need to expand your question for two sides.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And, I guess you've used the Lua debugger to show those boundaries?

Comment: @Atcold Used `showframe` option  in `geometry`. See last code. Please remember to update your question to include odd and even pages. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: The default for `marginnote` is ragged (left or right). My question was asking why `sidenotes` was going for a justified alignment. You did answer my question and provided a fix for `sidenotes` incorrect behaviour. Anyhow, I'll make it more explicit. Thanks again for your help! And thanks for the `showframe` tip!!